# Trying to sort rows by a column in views twig template

Tags: 8, views

I'm trying to sort the rows of a view in the table template but can't figure out how to sort by a particular column. I can only get it to sort by the first column. I'm trying to sort a views global conditional field so I can't use views query alter. Here's the code that sorts by the first column. I've tried various arrow functions without any luck.((a, b) => a.row.column <=> b.row.column).

```
<tbody>
  {% for row in rows|sort %}
    <tr{{ row.attributes }}>
      {% for key, column in row.columns %}
        {% if column.default_classes %}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194470/twig-sort-array-of-objects-by-field

Comment: Thanks @cilefen  I think I asked the question badly. How do I access the column numbers as indicated in the header of the template file?
 * - rows: Table row items. Rows are keyed by row number.
 *   - attributes: HTML classes to apply to each row.
 *   - columns: Row column items. Columns are keyed by column number.

Comment: I think this is essentially a Twig programming question. It’s hard to formulate an answer not really knowing what are the contents of the data. Output of the `dump` function would help this Question out.